# Google Nexus 7 3G free storage not recognised by Play store

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory

I have 85% free space of my 32 GB internal storage (there is no external sd card on this device), and yet I cannot download any new app or even update an old one, because Google Play Store keep telling me there is not enogh free space.
I am running Aopk ROM, tilapia-userdebug 4.2.2 JDQ39

Comment: I've just added the 'insufficient-memory' tag to your question. Please check its [tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first-aid. Does that help you to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting this error a lot lately (stock N7 16gb), too, and I have plenty of room on my device. Usually I can go back in and tell it to update and it will work the second time.

Just now I was getting an update message on an app and when I went in to update it there was no update option. I wonder if this is related to the new Google Play version coming out.

I went to Google Play on my laptop and told it to update the app and it worked that way.

You might try downloading the apk for the [new Play Store](http://androidfannetwork.com/2013/04/09/download-the-new-google-play-store-4-0-25/) and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Read all the posts but did not want to do software surgery on my Nextbook 7 while it was under warranty, so I called Nextbook support. After a long delay they gave me a solution that worked. I had little free memory so apps would not update even though I had only the original Google apps installed. For some reason the apps were duplicated in my internal storage partition. 
The solution is go to Bootloader by holding down the power and volume at startup. Then scroll down to Wipe data/factory reset click power and then yes. Now scroll down to Wipe Media Partition, click power and yes. Then Reboot system.

My memory went from 40 megs free to 260 megs free. All is good. I am betting this solves some of the other issues with performance as well.

Comment: Sounds kind of like using a cannon to kill a mosquito. You did a full factory reset just to get space back?